# How to run api-gateway(Netflix Zuul) and Eureka Server on different port in one Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I have a `Spring Boot` application which is `EurekaServer` as well as `ZuulServer`. My questions are:

- Is it possible to run both servers on different ports?
- If possible then, what should be the application configuration?

I have attached the configuration which I tried, but it's not giving me the desired output.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableZuulProxy
@EnableEurekaServer
public class AppApiGatewayApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AppApiGatewayApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

```
spring:
  application:
    name: gateway

server:
  port: 8001

eureka:
  instance:
   hostname: localhost
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:9090/eureka/
```

Comment: Why don't you create 2 seperate microservices for zuul and eureka?

Comment: @VarunMukundhan Creating separate microservice for both the servers will definitely work. I curious whether it's possible or not, to have a single microservice?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below

```
server:
  port: ${appPort:8880}
  additionalPorts: 8882,8883

# Spring MVC actuator endpoints available via /admin/info, /admin/health, ...
server.servlet-path: /
management:
  context-path: /admin
  port: 8881
```

The best way to design microservice is to have separate EurekaServer and register your ZuulServer to Eureka. Please refer below link

https://tech.asimio.net/2016/12/15/Configuring-Tomcat-to-Listen-on-Multiple-ports-using-Spring-Boot.html